# Get all tweets based on SPECIFIC word and STORE all tweets in SINGLE BAG

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to process the sample tweet and store the tweets based on the filtered criteria.

For example,

**sample tweet**:-

```
{"created_time": "18:47:31 ", "text": "RT @Joey7Barton: ..give a word about whether the americans wins a Ryder cup. I mean surely he has slightly more important matters. #fami ...", "user_id": 450990391, "id": 252479809098223616, "created_date": "Sun Sep 30 2012"}

twitter = LOAD 'Tweet.json' USING JsonLoader('created_time:chararray, text:chararray, user_id:chararray, id:chararray, created_date:chararray');
grouped = GROUP twitter BY (text,id);
filtered =FOREACH grouped { row = FILTER $1 BY (text MATCHES '.*word.*'); GENERATE FLATTEN(row);}
```

it gets the complete tweets which matches with the word.

But I need to get the output as below:

```
(word)(all tweets of contained that word)
```

How can I achieve this?

Any help.

Mohan.V

Answer (score 0):

After filtering add the word as a field say 'pattern' to the filtered relation and then group by that field.That will get you the word and a bag of tweets.

```
twitter = LOAD 'Tweet.json' USING JsonLoader('created_time:chararray, text:chararray, user_id:chararray, id:chararray, created_date:chararray');
grouped = GROUP twitter BY (text,id);
filtered =  FILTER $1 BY (text MATCHES '.*word.*');
newfiltered = FOREACH filtered GENERATE 'word' AS pattern,filtered.text;
final = GROUP newfiltered BY pattern;
DUMP final;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply inquisitive_mind.i'm trying an another scenario.i.e.